# Is my method running asynchronously?

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, xna, task

In my game, I noticed some freeze, due to the fact that `AdComponent` tries to download from internet a new Ad to be drawn on my game.

How the freezing function is initialized:

```
// Declarations
DrawableAd drawableAd;

// Inside constructor of my game class
AdComponent.Initialize("MyAppId");
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, resolution_h_ - 50, 320, 50);
drawableAd_ = AdComponent.Current.CreateAd("AdId", rect, false); // false is to set AutoRefresh of the ad
```

To make the ad clickable and to download it, I have to call in every update step:  `AdComponent.Current.Update(e_.ElapsedTime);`

[DrawableAd infos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524163%28v=msads.20%29.aspx)

The problem is that if I call it synchronously it make my game freeze for some time while downloading a new ad:

```
private void OnUpdate(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
{
     // ... GameUpdates
     AdComponent.Current.Update(e.ElapsedTime); 
}
```

So, I though that the solution was to put `AdComponent.Current.Update(e.ElapsedTime);` on a background-thread, with "low priority" to solve freeze problem. So i did:

```
  private async void UpdateAds()
  {
      if (ad_update_completed_)
          await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateAdsMethod());
  }

  private async Task UpdateAdsMethod()
  {
      ad_update_completed_ = false;
      AdComponent.Current.Update(e_.ElapsedTime);
      ad_update_completed_ = true;
  }

  private void OnUpdate(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
  {
     // ... GameUpdates
     e_ = e;
     UpdateAds();
  }
```

After this, I noticed (without using a profiler) that most of the freezes (not all) where gone. But I have some doubt because the compiler is giving a warning saying that `UpdateAdsMethod();` will be executed synchronously.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: async != multithreading. There is not enough information to help optimise your code.

Comment: @Aron What informations can I add?

Comment: The results you got from a profiler of course.

Comment: A few comments outside the scope of your question: 1) Don't use `async void` (except for event handlers), use `async Task` if it doesn't return any results. 2) There's no reason for you to use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Just `await UpdateAdsMethod`.

Comment: @Aron "async != multithreading" In the realm of **async** and **Task** it is

Comment: @MickyDuncan You are sooo wrong. `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.Run` are multithreaded. `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` should in most cases cause you to run in a ThreadPool thread also. But also it should be possible to run the code async single threaded and maintain 30fps on the UI. EASILY. Using `Task.Yield()`.

Comment: @aron _"enough information to help optimise your code"_.  Incorrect

Comment: @Aron Incorrect.  "ConfigureAwait(
    continueOnCapturedContext: false);
  // Code here runs without the original
  // context (in this case, **on the thread pool**)." - MSDN Magazine .  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @Aron Guess you don't know how IAsyncResult works and how **async, Task** are lovely hi-level abstractions that the compiler code-gens IAsyncResult equivalent code.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Please read [Stephen Cleary's There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). Clearly you don't understand that IAsyncResult does not neccessarily need a thread. In fact it is usually used where there is no thread, thus you NEED a callback to bring you back to a thread, with a CPU and memory and call stack...

Comment: FYI Stephen Cleary is a Microsoft MVP who happened to have signed a NDA with Microsoft re: `async` `await`.

Comment: @Aron Stephen Cleary is talking about I/O Completion ports which use threads you silly person. http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/multithreaded-asynchronous-io-io-comple/201202921 MVP? Well I'm a Microsoft Partner. Your ignorance in conjunction with your arrogance are quite astounding.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Now I am pretty confused. It seems you know about this stuff. But what I have a problem with is the original statement. Async == multithreading. That is generically just not true. You should know this, but why on earth would you say it...It is just asynchronicity, which does not necessitate a new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AdComponent.Current.Update**() does not return a **Task** so your **UpdateAdsMethod** can be simplified (see below).  Since you are calling **UpdateAdsMethod**() inside a child task, there is no need to have it return another task. It should simply read as follows:

```
    private void UpdateAdsMethod()
    {
        ad_update_completed_ = false;
        AdComponent.Current.Update(e_.ElapsedTime);
        ad_update_completed_ = true;
    }
```

That should eliminate the compiler warning.  Remember, if in any method you use **await** keyword, the signature for the method that is using an **await** must include **async** on the method declaration.  See **UpdateAds()** below.

Your method is certainly running in the background because the call is in a child task (you created it during **UpdateAds**().

**EDIT:**  So your code should now resemble:

```
private async Task UpdateAds()
    {
        if (ad_update_completed_)
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateAdsMethod());
    }

    private void UpdateAdsMethod()
    {
        ad_update_completed_ = false;
        AdComponent.Current.Update(e_.ElapsedTime);
        ad_update_completed_ = true;
    }
```

For more information visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Do you agree with Daniel Mann comment? Should I remove `StartNew`?

Comment: @misiMe Not sure what he means in #2.  Doing so results in many _"Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call"_ compiler warnings

Comment: I can't believe how much I disagree with you. `UpdateAdsMethod()` looks to be thread unsafe. If `public void UpdateAdsMethod` throws you can't catch it and your entire application will stop running. You should return a Task then wrap that in a Try Catch. Finally the name "DrawableAdComponent" suggests the need for UI threading.

Comment: @Aron Now you are just trolling.  Go away